# Custom ODBC driver implementation in GO

Tags: windows, go, odbc

I'm trying to develop an odbc driver in Go for Windows, for our internal/custom db; I saw many codes (like
https://github.com/LukeMauldin/lodbc for example), but I don't know how to act...
All SQL* function are already implemented (and all examples tell to do not touch the implementation) and, honestly, I've some difficult to understand where I need to modify in order to add my customization.

Is there any example/doc I can follow to do some experiment?

Thanks in advance